# How to Match Redundant Lines From Contenteditable Div in Regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to process the html inside a contenteditable div. It might look like:

```
<div>Hi I'm Jack...</div>
<div><br></div>
<div><br></div>
<div>More text.</div> *<div><br></div>*

*<div><br></div>**<div><br></div>*
*<div><br></div>*
*<div>
    <br>
</div>*
```

What regex expression would match all trailing `<div><br></div>` but not the ones sandwiched between useful divs containing text, i.e., `<div> text (not html) </div>`?

**I have enclosed all expressions I want to match in asterisks. The asterisk are for reference only and are not part of my string.**

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: you only want to match this `<div><br></div>` and nothing else???

Comment: Yes - I'm quite new to regex. Apologies if very easy.

Comment: Why is the 7th line matched but not the second or third?

Comment: Because (as far as contenteditable divs go) the 7th is "trailing whitespace". The second and third lines are useful - they are separating `<div>Hi, I'm Jack...</div> ` from `<div>More text.</div>`.

Comment: @Jack Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pattern:

```
(?:<div>[\n\s]*<br>[\n\s]*<\/div>)(?!.*?<div>[^<]+<\/div>)
```

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/KIZdgE/4).

Let me know if this works for all your cases and I will write a detailed explanation of the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This one isn't matching the `<div><br></div>` directly after `<div>More text.</div>`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. After removing the asterisks (which were just for reference), it no longer works.

Comment: Your question is not clear then. Do you want [this](https://regex101.com/r/eKrjcS/3) ? **(link)**

Comment: I've added a comment in the code in my answer which I should have included in the first place.

Comment: Why do you not want to match `<div><br></div>` in the sixth line? Have you tried [the latest update](https://regex101.com/r/eKrjcS/4) ?

Comment: Please edit your question, with a separate section where you show what should be matched.

Comment: I really appreciate all your help, but unfortunately it still doesn't get the first one on line 6.

Comment: @Jack Sorry about the delay. Please check [the updated pattern](https://regex101.com/r/KIZdgE/4). I simplified it and matches all strings you required. Let me know.

Comment: @Jack Happy to help!